# How to select a button / cause a callback in Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I can't find any example of how to start a bot action as a Telegram client using Telethon. The message has the `buttons` parameter, but that's only for the bot's sending side. How do I respond to such message?

For example I get a message with:

```
        reply_markup=ReplyInlineMarkup(
                rows=[
                        KeyboardButtonRow(
                                buttons=[
                                        KeyboardButtonCallback(
                                                text='⇱ Main Menu',
                                                data=b'main_menu',
                                                requires_password=False
                                        ),
                                        KeyboardButtonCallback(
                                                text='↵ Back',
                                                data=b'back',
                                                requires_password=False
                                        ),
                                ]
                        ),
                ]
        ),
```

How would I trigger the `main_menu` action in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Message.click`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html?highlight=Message%20click#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.click):

```py
await message.click(0)  # the first button
# or
await message.click(data=b'back')  # the button with data 'back'
# ...among others
```